# Control speed of gif in C#?

Tags: c#, gif

Is there any way to control the speed of animation of a GIF image in C#?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/ThreadPool11212005035101AM/ThreadPool.aspx

Comment: What sort of UI are you using? Web, WinForms, WPF, SilverLight? How are you displaying the GIF? An image control of some sort? Something you wrote yourself?

Comment: WInForms. The GIF is displayed through a simple PictureBox control.

Answer (score 3):

The speed of an animated GIF is part of the actual file's header. Hence, there are two ways to  control the speed of an animated GIF:

- One way is to write your application to ignore the frame rate data in
  the file's header. Doing this will involve writing some lower level
  code rather than relying on whatever pre-made libraries you are
  using.
- Another solution would be to change the frame rate data in the
  file itself before loading it. Again this will require some research,
  but it has the benefit of not having to create your own custom image
  viewer control.

Good luck.